# How to include css in bundle w/ rollup.js Unable to load css files - Unexpected token

Tags: css, babeljs, rollupjs

I am currently running into an error trying to bundle/load a CSS file in a component library using roll up.js. I keep running into an unexpected token error which is leading me to believe it's not recognizing the extension. I have tried `including` CSS files in the babel plugin, that didn't work. Adding the `postcss` pluging resulted in my getting this error rather than my previous error `Can not resolve DropDown.css` but now I'm stuck. Any ideas?

The error:

```
[!] (babel plugin) SyntaxError: /Users/adam.mateo/Documents/code/quovo-app/shared-components/components/DropDown/DropDown.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
components/DropDown/DropDown.css (1:0)
SyntaxError: /Users/adam.mateo/Documents/code/quovo-app/shared-components/components/DropDown/DropDown.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .Dropdown-root {
    | ^
  2 |   position: relative;
  3 | }
  4 |
```

My rollup.config:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
  input: 'components/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/main.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      plugins: [
        'transform-object-rest-spread',
        // 'external-helpers',
      ],
      presets: [
        'react',
        ['env', { 'modules': false }],
      ],
    }),
    postcss({
       extensions: ['.css'],
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using a separate plugin for this: [rollup-plugin-scss](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss). It captures all spare `.css` files imported in the components, and aggregates into a single CSS bundle that comes as part of a rollup output package.

A very simple configuration that suits my needs, looks like this:

```
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
...

export default {
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [...],
  plugins: [
    ...
    scss(),
  ]
}
```

There seems to be more options to enhance it, if needed.